# Function to give non-repetitive high-contrast number, dependent on given integer seed between 0 and 90!-1 and returns number between 0 and 90!-1

Tags: python, encryption

I need a function that I will use in my primitive encryption function. It pseudo-randomizes a list of 90 characters, that are later processed. This is a code I use for it:

```
a = [(numbers from 0 to 89)]
b = []
p = function(number between 0 and 90!-1)
for i in range(81,0,-1):
    b.append(a[p % i])
    a.pop(p % i)
    p //= i
```

I want the function to, for example, if I enter low numbers, it gives some higher number, but if I would have run this function for all numbers between 0 and 90!-1, there wouldn't be 2 same numbers. In the past, I just used random module and I was using a seed() function, but I want to write something by myself, so that if python devs change random module, it won't break my decryption.

Comment: You could try relying on a specific pseudo-random algorithm to get some consistent randomness. For example, the SHA-256 hash of some constant string will *always* be the same. No version of python (or any other program) will change that algorithm just because they feel like it.

Comment: I don't know what a *non-repetitive high-contrast number* is. Can you explain it? It almost sounds like you want a permutation of the integers in [0, 90!).

Comment: By high contrast I meant something to the effect of there being huge differences between functions of similar numbers. For example, if I had similar function for numbers between 0 and 9, I would like it to return something like 7 for 0, 3 for 1, 9 for 2, 1 for 3, 5 for 4, 8 for 5, 2 for 6, 0 for 7, 4 for 8 and 6 for 9